# Scala - Is that a closure?

Tags: scala, closures

I am not sure whether the code I´ve just written can be called a closure, here it is:

```
withExistingDataSource(dataSourceId, dataSource => checkDataSourceTypeAndFetchDataFromAgent(dataSource, theQuery))
```

See following the previous method signature:

```
private def withExistingDataSource(dataSourceId: Long, success: DataSource => Result): Result
```

Can I state that:

```
dataSource => checkDataSourceTypeAndFetchDataFromAgent(dataSource, theQuery)
```

is a closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

The result of the function depends on the `theQuery` variable which is defined outside the function.

Comment: What if I get rid of the theQuery parameter?

Comment: Then you have a Function